# How to implement Slide to delete in Famo.us with proper event handling

Tags: famo.us

I'm trying to implement a slide to delete. As part of that I have a layer with opacity set to 0 the idea being I'm trying to set several if clauses to gradual change the opacity of the surface so that the word Delete gentle appears as you slide it to the left. At this point I just have it switching at 10pixels for testing. The functions fire but the opacity doesn't change. I think it has something to do with not being piped/event handling being done properly on my part. Any Ideas?

```
var SnapTransition = require("famous/transitions/SnapTransition");

    Transitionable.registerMethod('snap', SnapTransition);



    var CSS = require("css/recentActivityCSS");
    var Ctrl = require("controllers/recentActivityCtrl");

    var homeContentWrap = new Scrollview();

    var recentActivities = [];

    var ContainerSize = [undefined, 100];

    homeContentWrap.sequenceFrom(recentActivities);

    for (var i = 0; i < Ctrl.recentActivityList.length; i++) {

        var recentActivitiesContainer = new ContainerSurface({
            size: ContainerSize,
            properties: CSS.recentActivitiesContainer,
        });

        var redLayer = new Surface({
            size: ContainerSize,
            content: 'DELETE',
            properties: CSS.redLayer,
        });

        var draggable = new Draggable({
            xRange: [-120, 5],
            yRange: [0, 0],
        });

        var textContainer = new ContainerSurface({
            size: ContainerSize,
            properties: CSS.textContainer,
        });

        var mod = new Modifier({});
        node = new RenderNode(draggable);
        node.add(mod).add(textContainer);


        textContainer.pipe(draggable);
        textContainer.pipe(homeContentWrap);

        var opacityMod = new StateModifier({
            opacity: 0
        });

        recentActivitiesContainer.add(node);
        recentActivitiesContainer.add(opacityMod).add(redLayer);

        recentActivities.push(recentActivitiesContainer);


        var trans = {
          method: 'snap',
          period: 100,
          dampingRatio: 0.3,
          velocity: 5
        };


        draggable.on('start', function() {});
        draggable.on('update', function() {
            var position = this.getPosition();
            if (position[0] > (-10)) {
                opacityMod.halt();
                opacityMod.setOpacity(0, { curve: 'easeOut', duration: 10 });
            } else {
                opacityMod.halt();
                opacityMod.setOpacity(1, { curve: 'easeOut', duration: 10 });
            }
        });
        draggable.on('end', function(){
            var position = this.getPosition();
            if (position[0] < (-100)) {
                alert('delete');
            }
            this.setPosition([0,0,0], trans);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things I did to the draggable 'update' function to achieve what you have described.

1) You need to bind objects to your update function or else you have no real reference to them. When you use opacityMod in your 'update' function, you only alter the last cells opacityMod. Since binding will change the meaning of 'this', I also bind draggable.

2) You say you want a gradual fade. This approach is not going to give you anything gradual. You need to take the position of the draggable and calculate an opacity based on that value. To start, I declare two new variables for fadeStart and fadeEnd, that represent the positions of the draggable X position 0 and 1 opacity respectively.

Also you probably do not need the transition in your setOpacity, but I kept it in anyway.

Here is the updated 'update' function.. Good Luck!

```
fadeStart = -10;
fadeEnd   = -100;

draggable.on('update', function() {

    var draggable   = this[0];
    var opacityMod  = this[1];

    var position = draggable.getPosition();

    if ( position[0] > fadeStart ) {

        opacityMod.halt();
        opacityMod.setOpacity(0, { curve: 'easeOut', duration: 10 });

    } else if ( position[0] > fadeEnd ) {

        opacity = (position[0] - fadeStart) / ( fadeEnd - fadeStart );

        opacityMod.halt();
        opacityMod.setOpacity(opacity, { curve: 'easeOut', duration: 10 });

    } else {

        opacityMod.halt();
        opacityMod.setOpacity(1, { curve: 'easeOut', duration: 10 });
    }

}.bind([draggable,opacityMod]));
```

Comment: Thanks, This is what I was headed towards but when the set opacity wouldn't work I didn't re-factor to set up the gradual change. I was pretty sure I needed to bind of pipe just haven't got my head completely around the event handling.

Comment: Yea the event handling was fine! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

John has clearly answered this question above, but I wanted to show an alternate approach to the problem. I've seen questions here and in the #famous irc where people are having eventing problems. I've also seen a number of people struggling with binding or the lack of it. And finally, if you work out the whole slide thing here, shouldn't you be able to put that behind you and simply drop it in elsewhere? With that in mind I wrote a program that simply puts several images into a scrollview. Then I wrote a function called createSlidePanel that encapsulated the slide functionality and then to enable the fade-in of the word "delete" I created a second helper function createModifyingView. This approach appears to hit all three points above. I broke the eventing problems down into smaller more manageable units. It completely eliminated the need for this and binding. And finally, the two helper functions can be reused.

Here is my version of "main.js" which contains fundamentally "application" behavior:

```
/* globals define */
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    'use strict';
    // import dependencies
    var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
    var ImageSurface = require('famous/surfaces/ImageSurface');
    var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
    var Scrollview = require('famous/views/Scrollview');
    var SnapTransition = require('famous/transitions/SnapTransition');
    var Transitionable = require('famous/transitions/Transitionable');

    var createSlidePanel = require('SlidePanel');
    var createModifyingView = require('ModifyingView');

    Transitionable.registerMethod('snap', SnapTransition);
    var trans = {
      method: 'snap',
      period: 100,
      dampingRatio: 0.3,
      velocity: 5
    };

    var dataSource = [
        'http://www.outerspaceuniverse.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/outer-space1.jpg',
        'http://wallpoper.com/images/00/39/95/84/outer-space_00399584.jpg',
        'http://static1.businessinsider.com/image/508c649e69beddb270000005/the-only-reason-private-space-flight-isnt-laughed-at-is-nasas-11-billion-infusion.jpg'
    ];
    var images = [];

    var slideOptions = {
        drag: {
            xRange: [-120, 5],
            projection: 'x',
        },
        view: {
            size:[300,300]
        }
    };

    var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
    var scrollView = new Scrollview();
    mainContext.add(scrollView);

    dataSource.forEach(function(url,i,urls) {
        var img = new ImageSurface({
            content: url,
            size: [300,300]
        });

        var dlt = new Surface({
            size:[300,300],
            content: 'DELETE',
            properties: {
                color: 'red',
                zIndex: 4,
                lineHeight: '200px',
                fontSize:'60px'
            }
        });
        var modView = createModifyingView();
        modView.modifier.setOpacity(0);
        modView.add(dlt);

        var elem = createSlidePanel(slideOptions);
        elem.addSlide(img)
        elem.addStill(modView);
        elem._eventOutput.pipe(scrollView);
        elem.on('slideupdate',slideUpdateHandler);
        elem.on('slideend',slideEndHandler);

        images.push(elem);
    });

    function slideUpdateHandler(eventInfo) {
        var ratio = (eventInfo.data.position[0]-slideOptions.drag.xRange[1])/(slideOptions.drag.xRange[0]-slideOptions.drag.xRange[1]);
        if(ratio>.2) {
            eventInfo.source.stillElements[0].modifier.setOpacity(ratio);
        } else {
            eventInfo.source.stillElements[0].modifier.setOpacity(0);
        }
    }

    function slideEndHandler(eventInfo) {
        if (eventInfo.data.position[0] < (-100)) {
            alert('delete');
        }
        eventInfo.source.modifier.setPosition([0,0,0], trans);
        eventInfo.source.stillElements[0].modifier.setOpacity(0);
    }

    scrollView.sequenceFrom(images);

});
```

The slide functionality is here in "SlidePanel.js":

```
/* globals define */
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    'use strict';
    // import dependencies
    var Modifier        = require('famous/core/Modifier');
    var View            = require('famous/core/View');
    var Draggable       = require('famous/modifiers/Draggable');


    function createSlidePanel(options) {
        options = options || {};

        var slidePanel = new View(options.view);
        slidePanel.slideElements = [];
        slidePanel.stillElements = [];

        slidePanel.modifier = new Draggable(options.drag);

        var node = slidePanel._add(slidePanel.modifier);

        slidePanel.addSlide = function addSlide(renderable) {
            node.add(renderable);
            renderable.pipe(slidePanel._eventOutput);
            renderable.pipe(slidePanel.modifier);
            slidePanel.slideElements.push(renderable);
        }

        slidePanel.addStill = function addStill(renderable) {
            slidePanel.add(renderable);
            renderable.pipe(slidePanel._eventOutput);
            renderable.pipe(slidePanel.modifier);
            slidePanel.stillElements.push(renderable);
        }

        slidePanel.modifier.on('start',function(data) {
            slidePanel._eventOutput.emit('slidestart',{source:slidePanel,data:data});
        });
        slidePanel.modifier.on('update',function(data) {
            slidePanel._eventOutput.emit('slideupdate',{source:slidePanel,data:data});
        });
        slidePanel.modifier.on('end',function(data) {
            slidePanel._eventOutput.emit('slideend',{source:slidePanel,data:data});
        });

        slidePanel.modifier.activate();
        return slidePanel;
    }

    module.exports = createSlidePanel;
});
```

And here is the "ModifyingView.js" code:

```
/* globals define */
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    'use strict';
    // import dependencies
    var Modifier        = require('famous/core/Modifier');
    var View            = require('famous/core/View');

    function createModifyingView(options) {
        options = options || {};

        var view = new View(options);
        view.modifier = new Modifier();
        var node = view._add(view.modifier);


        view.add = function add(renderable) {
            node.add(renderable);
            view._eventOutput.subscribe(renderable);
        };

        view.setPosition = function setPosition(/* passthrough */) {
            view.modifier.setPosition(arguments);
        };

        view.setOpacity = function setOpacity(/* passthrough */) {
            view.modifier.setOpacity(arguments)
        }
        //view.modifier.setPosition([0,0,0]);

        return view;
    }

    module.exports = createModifyingView;
});
```

Several Notes:

Obviously, one of the main changes here is the functional pattern which makes all references explicit and leaves no question of binding.

Yes this is more code than the original, partly because it is complete with all of the require statements and the list of images, but also because it just is. The trade-off here is that you may get more bang for the buck if you reuse the helpers.

The ModifyingView pattern is one I use quite a bit. This comes up so often whether I'm building a login form with eight surfaces interacting in ways the main program need know nothing about, or a simple surface fading in and out, that I have a code snippet which defines a view, a modifier, a statemodifier (one of which I usually delete,) a surface and much of the common code to tie them together.

I'm specifically not recommending the "options" management used in this code, but it suffices for the example.